# After calculating two values continuously, how can I stop calculation at a specific number?

Tags: php

I have set the value of (start) equal to 4 and it should increase +2 every time I click continue. It works fine, but I need it to stop counting when the value of (start) becomes bigger then 10,

```
<?php
$number=array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'g', 'j');
$start=2;     
$len = isset($_GET['len']) ? (int)$_GET['len'] : 2; 
$s = isset($_GET['start']) ? (int)$_GET['start']+2 : 4; 

foreach ($number as $value) {       
    print_r($value) ; 
}
echo '<br>'.'<br>';

if (isset($_GET['start']))
    $start = $_GET['start'];

foreach (array_slice($number,$start,$len) as $k){
    print_r($k);
}
echo '<br>'.'<br>';                       

if(is_numeric($start)) {   
    echo '<a href="http://192.168.1.6/alpha.php?start='.$s.'&len=2">continue</a>';
} else {
    echo "not a nummber";
}                                 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know in any moment the value of $start. So everywhere in the file you can do

```
if ($start>0) {
// do something
}
```

For example, if  I understand well the question, you don't want to show "continue" when $start > 10. Just do so:

```
    $number=array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'g', 'j');
$start=2;     
$len = isset($_GET['len']) ? (int)$_GET['len'] : 2; 
$s = isset($_GET['start']) ? (int)$_GET['start']+2 : 4; 

foreach ($number as $value) {       
    print_r($value) ; 
}
echo '<br>'.'<br>';

if (isset($_GET['start']))
$start = $_GET['start'];

foreach (array_slice($number,$start,$len) as $k){
    print_r($k);
}
echo '<br>'.'<br>';                       

if(is_numeric($start)) {   
    if ($start<=10) {
        echo '<a href="test.php?start='.$s.'&len=2">continue</a>';
    }
    } else {
    echo "not a nummber";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `break;` function on the `foreach` (this will stop the loop on the current iteration), or if you know the amount at which you want the loop to stop, you could use a `for` loop, something along the lines of this:

```
//Assuming $start = 0;
for($start <= 10; $start++){
    echo("continue")
}
```

If you're wanting to add +2 to `$start` each time, You will need to change `$start++` to `$start+2`.

Comment: I am intending to print (continue) 10times , i meant to make the loop stop running once the value of $start is bigger than 10

Comment: Yes but i don't know where exactly it is, once I set the loop it is not working, where exactly should I set the loop ?